# ¿Como utilizar el ciclo for para ntroducior unos valores en un arreglo?

Tags: javascript

¿Como utilizar el ciclo for para ntroducior unos valores en un arreglo en Javascript?

Comment: Muestranos que has hecho hasta el momento. Y de paso ve a [ask]

Answer (score 0):

para agregar valores a un `arreglo` o `lista`, primero esta debe estar declarada, posteriormente (dependiendo del origen de los datos) vas agregando cda uno de los registros, no necesariamnte usando un `ciclo for` sino el propio metodo para agregar a lista en js

```
    var arr = [
  "1",
  "2",
  "3"
];

// agregar nuevo valor al array
arr.push(4);

console.log(arr);
```

espero te ayude.

Comment: Si bien tu respuesta es correcta, no es lo que él OP pregunta... Te sugiero vayas a [answer]

Comment: Muchas gracias viejo!

Comment: var array_1 =[];
for(var i=0; i<6 ; i++){
    array_1.push(i)
}

console.log(array_1);